# How to call user registration form in php

Tags: php, forms, joomla, registration

I am trying to call the default joomla user registration form through a custom module with link. I created a popup box and i would like to show the user login and user registration inside that popup box. I just need the call for the forms. Thanks

Comment: Which version of Joomla you are using?

Comment: I am usign joomla 2.5 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getInstance() method of JForm where the first parameter is the name form (arbitrary) and the second parameter is the absolute path to the xml containing the form (in joomla forms are created with xml files).

```
<?php
    /* @var $form JForm */
    $form = JForm::getInstance('formName', JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml');
    foreach ($form->getFieldset() as $field) {
        echo JText::_($field->label);
        echo $field->input;
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan

Answer (score 0):

The custom module should be published to a component if you want to be able to access it. You can achieve this with com_content and the {loadposition } code.

Once you have your module in a component, you need to figure out a link to it, it could be:

http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=115

of a sef-url if you define a menu item.

To invoke just the component (thus the module's) output, add

&tmpl=component

to the url, this will tell Joomla to only render the component and not the full template